# Can QGIS open the file type .pitemx or .pkinfo?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, pkinfo

The following file types are associated with ArcMap(.pitemx) and ArcGIS Pro(.pkinfo).

Can QGIS open the file types *.pitemx* or *.pkinfo*?

Please see the example image & weblink below for where to download the file types.

ArcGIS map: https://exchange.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9c76293962a041e1853d573ae36c1d34

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. It takes a bit of doing/navigating, but under 3.18 at least, you can access the ArcGIS Server REST endpoint to add the data to your local project with ease.

In other cases, you could accomplish it by loading the *.lyr files using SLYR by North Road/Nyall Dawson.

Getting the REST endpoint URL is possible by opening your linked item in the web viewer:
[image]
then selecting the triple dots on it in the Web Map Content to Show Item Details, and then clicking Source: Map Service under Details to get to the ArcGIS REST endpoint.

[image]

From there, copy the URL for the services breadcrumb (in this case, https://services.arcgisonline.co.nz/arcgis/rest/services)
[image]
and create a new connection under the Data Source Manager for ArcGIS REST Server.

You should see the data listed out like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Can QGIS open the file types .pitemx or .pkinfo?**

The answer is no. QGIS cannot directly open these file types.

A pkinfo file is an xml reference to an ArcGIS Online map id, which enables ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Desktop products to open the map.

Saijin_Naib has shown how QGIS can open the *individual map layers via the services* that have been configured for the map and this is very good information.

This solution will create a connection to the data and display the style/filters that are applied at the service level, however it **might** not - in all cases - display the data in the same way it is configured in ArcGIS Online.

This is because an AGOL Map may contain different map services (WMS/WFS, ESRI Map Services and ESRI Feature Services, Tile Services) but more importantly, these services can have map style, visibility and filters **applied on the client side** (That is - these styles and filters are not saved at the service level, they are applied by the AGOL Map.)

In these instances, your service connection from within QGIS will display data associated with the service, BUT may not necessarily have the same display/style/attribute info as what an AGOL Map has configured.

This will vary upon how the map has been created and the services used. In some cases, using the services will be fine and give you the exact same. In other cases you may need to rebuild the filters/styles from within QGIS.